# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No valid credential configuration discovered" error when authenticating Hadoop-GCS connector

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to load data into GCP using Spark from outside of GCP (from one of our on-prem clusters). To do that, I wrote the following code.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .set("spark.network.timeout", "12000s")
  .set("spark.kryoSerializer.buffer.max", "512m")
  .set("temporaryGcsBucket", "GCS_BUCKET_LOCATION")
  .setAppName(args(1))
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Loader]))

val spark = SparkSession.builder().
  appName("app").
  master("yarn").
  config( "spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").
  config(conf).
  getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("temporaryGcsBucket", "GCS_BUCKET_LOCATION")
spark.conf.set("parentProject", "PROJECTID")

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "/path/to/application_default_credentials.json")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.client.id", "CLIENTID")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.client.secret", "SECRETKEY")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.project.id", "PROJECTID")
```

Spark Read:

```
val dataframe = spark.read.format("jdbc")
          .option("url", s"jdbc:sqlserver://$server;DatabaseName=$databasename")
          .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
          .option("user", "USERNAME")
          .option("password", "PASSWORD")
          .option("dbtable", query)
          .option("partitionColumn", partitionColumn)
          .option("lowerBound", SOMEVALUE)
          .option("upperBound", SOMEVALUE)
          .option("numPartitions", numPartitions)
          .option("fetchsize", 10000)
          .load()
```

Spark Write:

```
dataframe.drop(s"${partitionColumn}1")
          .write.format("parquet")
          .option("parentProject", "PROJECTNAME")
          .option("path", s"gs://SOME_GCS_PATH/${tablename}")
          .option("credentialsFile","/path/of/jsonfile/on/local/application_default_credentials.json")
          .mode("append")
          .save()
```

When I run the code, I see the below error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No valid credential configuration discovered:  [CredentialOptions{serviceAccountEnabled=false, serviceAccountPrivateKeyId=<redacted>, serviceAccountPrivateKey=<redacted>, serviceAccountEmail=hadoop-distp-sa-hadoop@ktest.imp.gserviceaccount.com, serviceAccountKeyFile=null, serviceAccountJsonKeyFile=/path/of/jsonfile/on/local/application_default_credentials.json, nullCredentialEnabled=false, transportType=JAVA_NET, tokenServerUrl=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token, proxyAddress=null, proxyUsername=null, proxyPassword=null}]
```

So I tried to add the configuration as per the method3 present in Authentication section of [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/CONFIGURATION.md) page.

and made the following changes to my configuration:

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "false")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.impersonation.service.account.for.user.<USER_NAME>", "username@companyname.com")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.impersonation.service.account.for.group.<GROUP_NAME>", "gcp_projectid")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.impersonation.service.account", "service-account-name@.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
```

But I am still running into the same exception even after changing the configuration as per the above mentioned link.

Is there any thing that I am doing wrong here ?
Could anyone let me know how can I fix the issue and what are the mandatory configuration parameters to provide in spark code to authenticate with GCP ?
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the documentation you've linked, you're using the GCS connector, therefore I believe that:

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.impersonation.service.account.for.user.<USER_NAME>", "username@companyname.com")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.impersonation.service.account.for.group.<GROUP_NAME>", "gcp_projectid")
```

Should actually contain the same values as:

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.impersonation.service.account", "service-account-name@.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
```

Because the `<USER_NAME>` and `<GROUP_NAME>` sections ought to be changed to `username@companyname.com` and `gcp_projectid` respectively, at least according to the [section in the documentation pertaining to these values](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/CONFIGURATION.md#:%7E:text=The%20service%20account%20impersonation%20for%20a%20specific%20user)
Given that the value for the third configuration is the account, I believe the others should be too... They're just there in case you want to specify user-specific or group-specific service accounts to use.

That being said, I believe those values are being ignored, as there's likely no user with the username `<USER_NAME> in your project, and instead would like to know a little more about this configuration:

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "false")
```

As you mention it as being part of the previous documentation, but I cannot seem to find it there? The only instance I can quickly find of said configuration option has it [enabled](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md), which is to say that the option is set to "true", without this option a service account won't be used, which seems odd considering you have declared which service account to use. Or at least that's the information I could glean from the following descriptive text:

```
    Whether to use a service account for GCS authorization.
    Setting this property to `false` will disable use of service accounts for
    authentication.
```

However, if that's the case, then it should most definitely warn you when this property is set to false and the other is set to a value that is not null, I believe.

So, reading over your post again... I believe you're overwriting the original configuration you've put with the "following changes to the configuration", but those changes do not include `google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile`, which I believe is necessary, but I can't say for sure, as the only things I've found within Google's docs are using [Cloud Interconnect](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/hadoop/hadoop-gcp-migration-data), so it's hard for me to say whether or not it's applicable in your case, as you're doing this from Spark and are not using [DiskCTP](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to an incompatible argument used in the authentication configuration. The below authentication configurations have been removed from the Hadoop-GCS connector since January, 2021 and are not supported in the latest version. Connector version [`2.1.6`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/releases/tag/v2.1.6) was the last to support these configuration parameters. You can refer to the change history [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/releases/tag/v2.2.0) (point #24).

```
fs.gs.auth.client.id
fs.gs.auth.client.file
fs.gs.auth.client.secret
```

To authenticate with a service account JSON key file, use the following configuration.

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "/path/to/service_account_json_key_file.json")
```

---

The supported authentication methods in the latest version (`v2.2.3`) of the connector are discussed in the [connector configuration properties](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/CONFIGURATION.md#authentication). Quoting required parts from the md file.

##### **Service account authentication**

> The following properties are required only when running **not on a GCE
> VM** and `fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable` is `true`. There are 3 ways
> to configure these credentials, which are mutually exclusive.
>
> **Method 1:** Configure service account details directly in the Configuration file or via Hadoop Credentials.
>
> **Method 2:** Configure service account credentials using a json keyfile.
>
> **Method 3:** Configure service account credentials using a P12 certificate.

##### **Service account impersonation**

> Service account impersonation can be configured for a specific user
> name and a group name, or for all users by default using below
> properties:
>
> - `fs.gs.auth.impersonation.service.account.for.user.<USER_NAME>` (not set by default)
>
> The service account impersonation for a specific user.
>
> - `fs.gs.auth.impersonation.service.account.for.group.<GROUP_NAME>` (not set by default)
>
> The service account impersonation for a specific group.
>
> - `fs.gs.auth.impersonation.service.account` (not set by default)
>
> Default service account impersonation for all users.
>
> If any of the above properties are set then the service account
> specified will be impersonated by generating a short-lived credential
> when accessing Google Cloud Storage.
>
> Configured authentication method will be used to authenticate the
> request to generate this short-lived credential.